# How to make checkbox background transparent?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

i use the following code to make check box background transparent or in my case off white but i can't find what wrong with this plz help me how to do this?

```
HBRUSH CfvcolorDlg::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
 HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

 pDC->SetBkColor(MYCOLOR);

 if((HBRUSH)brush == NULL)
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(MYCOLOR);
 return (HBRUSH) brush;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where is 'brush' declared? As you posted it it won't even compile.

Comment: CfvcolorDlg.h  as CBrush brush